# Custom upload file on Prestashop page

Tags: php, file-upload, prestashop

I made a separate page ([following this guide](http://gmdavid.com/crear-pagina-personalizada-prestashop/)) so he can upload pdf files (certificates of their products). And another page to the customer's search according to the selected product.

On the file upload page, the logic is as follows:

In a form:
Select the product (from a selector), and then select the certificate (pdf) to upload.

Submit button stored in a table (created by me) the product ID and the certificate name and attribute (soon to be able to do the search.)

In the database the data is saved correctly, but in the ftp folder files are not saved.

Here I show you my code in /themes/ theme /certificados.tpl

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="subirconnect.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select id="producto" name="producto">
        <option value="default" selected>Producto</option>
        ...
    </select>

    <select id="attr" name="attr">  
        <option value="default" selected>Diametro</option>
        ...
    </select>

    <input type="file" name="adjunto[]" multiple="multiple">

    <input type="submit" value="Subir" name="enviar_certificados" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Validate form:

```
$TamanioMaximo=5000000;  // 1000000 ~~~ 1mb 
$CarpetaAlojamiento='../../certificados'; // path public_html/certificados
$NombreArchivoFinal="";
$MensajeCertificados="";

if(!empty($_POST['enviar_certificados'])) {

  $name_producto = $_POST['producto'];
  $name_combinacion = $_POST['attr']; 
  $name_certificados = $_FILES['adjunto']['name'];

  $cntFiles = count($name_certificados);

  for ($i=0; $i< $cntFiles; $i++) { //for multiples files

    if($_FILES['adjunto']['size'][$i]>$TamanioMaximo) {
      $MensajeCertificados= 'El archivo debe pesar menos de 5mb';

    } else {

      if (!is_dir($CarpetaAlojamiento)) {
        mkdir($CarpetaAlojamiento);
        chmod($CarpetaAlojamiento, 0777);
      }

      $NombreArchivoFinal=$CarpetaAlojamiento."/".$_FILES['adjunto']['name'][$i];

      if(substr($_FILES['adjunto']['type'][$i],12,3) != 'pdf') {
        $MensajeCertificados= 'Solo se permiten archivos .PDF';

      } else if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'][$i], $NombreArchivoFinal);    

        $name_certificados = $_FILES['adjunto']['name'][$i];

        /* upload data to db - works fine*/
        SubirCertificados($cntFiles, $name_producto, $name_combinacion, $name_certificados);

        $MensajeCertificados = '¡Certificado Subido!';

      } else {
        $MensajeCertificados=  'Problemas en el envío '.$_FILES['adjunto']['name'][$i];
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

The folder 'certificados' is already created and has the necessary permissions (777)

You may be missing? move_uploaded_file not working in prestashop?
This same code works fine on my localhost (WAMP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use static paths rather make folder in prestashop-root/upload/certificados

```
$CarpetaAlojamiento = _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.'certificados';
```

Comment: It works perfectly. thank you very much. Now there arose another disadvantage, smaller, but I have to solve it. The PDF link would look like: `<a href="mysite/upload/certificados/546.pdf" download="546.pdf">546.pdf</a>` but when clicking makes me 404 page not found. Have something to do the .htaccess?

Comment: I had to clean the .htaccess to make the files public. thanks